# Andriod Emulator can't find ip link set

Tags: android-emulator, mac-address

I am currently using an unrooted Huaweii LYO-LO1 and I am trying to change my mac address using Andriod Terminal Emulator. I found a website that told me to find out things like my current MAC address and I did all that. The last part told me to type the command:

"ip link set AAAA address XX:XX:XX:YY:YY:YY"

I did that by typing "ip link set wlan0 address 84:9F:B5:0A:95:1F" but the output said

/system/bin/sh: ip link set wlan0 address 84:9F:B5:0A:95:1F: not found

I tried reinstalling the app, rebooting my computer, everything but it's the same result. Still the same MAC address. Anybody know the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Don't type the double inverted commas (`""`) around the command. The command should be

```
ip link set wlan0 address 84:9F:B5:0A:95:1F
```